# VLOOKUP Multiple Search on same Row

Tags: excel

Hello everyone I am currently struggling on a system I am trying to create.
I am trying to capture information from one sheet to another sheet.

Sheet 1:(DATA SHEET TEST1.XLSX)
[image: REFERENCE PAGE - TEST.XLSX]

Sheet 2:(SEARCH SHEET BOOK2.XLSX)
[image: SHEET THAT GATHERS DATA FROM TEST.XLSX]

The current formula for BOOK2.xlsx

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,[TEST1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$I$23,1,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(A2,[TEST1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$I$23,3,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(A2,[TEST1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$I$23,6,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(A2,[TEST1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$I$23,9,FALSE)
```

How do I make it so when I search an item from TEST1.xlsx that is not in the first column display all the data in the same row even if it duplicates itself on BOOK2.xlsx?

Comment: Hi there! So, clarifying questions: You want to duplicate a row from Sheet 1 into Sheet 2 based on whether it contains "Test 0" through "Test 6"? So you would want Row 3 in Sheet 2 to read Test 6 | Test 5 | Test 4 | Test 7?

Basically, you want the {0, 1, 2, 3} set or {6, 5, 4, 7} set to print out in columns B:E when one member of the set respective sets appears in column A?

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much for understanding.. Is it like a small change in my formula that is missing a fix? I can't seem to figure it out..!

Comment: Unfortunately, VLOOKUP does not handle multiple criteria. Is this the exact data you are looking to replicate? Because you can use IFS and OR in each cell if so. Like `=IFS(OR(A4="Test0", A4="Test1", A4="Test2", A4="Test3"), "Test0", OR(A4="Test6", A4="Test5", A4="Test4", A4="Test7"), "Test6"` and increment the value_if_true for the corresponding test.

Comment: Ah, thing is we have over 5000 values so doing that one by one for each cell would be a killer. So there isn't really a way of capturing a random value from any row on a data sheet and displaying all the values from the same row even the searches value..